# Какова сложность выполнения запроса со вложенным Length (строки) в LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, time-complexity, length

Есть задача, нужно *найти наиболее длинное слово из этого списка, а из наиболее длинных — лексикографически первое слово*. В метод передаётся коллекция, нужно вернуть одно слово. В одну операцию, без использования сортировок, сложность должна быть не более O(N).

Вроде бы всё легко, однако ограничение по сложности уменьшает варианты ответов и здесь появляются вопросы. Самое близкое по простоте и скорости решение, с которым я смог определиться:

```
public static string GetLongest(IEnumerable<string> words)
{
    return words
        .Min(word => Tuple.Create(-word.Length, word)).Item2;
}
```

Ответ с одной стороны правильный, однако проблема в Length и LINQ, на сайте нет проверки по сложности. Все варианты решения, которые я смог придумать и найти(в т.ч. от других учеников) - с использованием свойства Length у строк. Я знаю, что само по себе свойство у строк имеет сложность O(1), Min() от LINQ O(N), однако человек в комментариях мне пояснил, что: *"механизмы LINQ сначала пройдутся циклом по всей коллекции и извлекут все значения Length и потом будут запускать механизмы сортировок, поиска max/min и т.д. То есть в лучшем случае общая сложность запроса будет не проще чем O(N * log(N))."*.

Соответственно, интересно насколько это правда, и каким способом возможно решить за O(N), если он прав. Интересна даже больше сложность данной операции, чем правильное решение.

Comment: Никаких log n [здесь нет](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Min.cs#L290).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> механизмы LINQ сначала пройдутся циклом по всей коллекции и извлекут все значения Length и потом будут запускать механизмы сортировок, поиска max/min и т.д. То есть в лучшем случае общая сложность запроса будет не проще чем O(N * log(N))

Сложность `O(N * log(N))` будет в случае использования сортировки. Но ведь **у вас нет сортировки**! Можете посмотреть [исходники](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Min.cs) `Linq`, для вычисления `Min` (и `Max`) сортировка не нужна, нужен просто один последовательный проход по элементам коллекции. И это логично, когда пишут нахождение минимума или максимума "вручную", то делают точно так же.

Поэтому сложность будет `O(N)` для получения всех `Length`, плюс `O(N)` для получения `Min`, то есть в итоге будет таки `O(N)`.

Comment: И ведь действительно, они не вложены...
Всё ещё плаваю в сложности алгоритмов. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Ilya Да, некоторая вложенность образуется при сортировке, но не при нахождении максимума/минимума